# Load CSS, JavaScript, images from parent directory with htaccess

Tags: javascript, html, css, .htaccess

I have site and one of the domains directing to subfolder of the root. In this folder I have a .htaccess file and PHP files - I need use the `css`, `js` and `images` from root directory.

Attached the folders scheme:

```
root/
-subfolder/
--.htaccess
--file.php
-css/
-js/
-img/
```

Comment: Have absolute links to css file like `/css/style.css`

Comment: @anubhava: `subfolder` is the public root. `/` translates to the `subfolder` directory.

Comment: It is not clear from the post. OP please clarify what is `DocumentRoot` value?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. Your **public root** is `subfolder`. Anything outside of it cannot be *publicly* accessed.

Put the CSS and JavaScript directories into the public root.

---

A different **and not recommended** approach is to create a PHP file to serve those files based on specific URL routes. Again **not recommended**. Just put the directories in the public root.